# Naming convention for "super" private methods that should only be called by certain callers?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Since there is nothing the C# language to prevent anywhere in a class calling a private method from within that class, is there a standard naming convention for methods which are only ever to be called by another exclusive method(s)?

Why? So someone else does not accidentally call the method (if they are aware of the convention).

For example when I have recursive method I often have another method which I want to be the exclusive caller of the method, then everyone should call that method not my recursive method directly. For example:

```
    private void FindPathToNode(Node currentNode, List<Node> visitedNodes, List<Node> path, int targetId, ref bool found)
    {
         ...
         FindPathToNode(node, visitedNodes, path, targetId, ref found);
    }

    private void FindPathToNode(Node startNode, int targetId)
    {
        var visitedNodes = new List<Node>();
        var path = new List<Node>();
        var found = false;
        FindPathToNode(startNode, visitedNodes, path, targetId, ref found);
    }
```

I like the idea of leading underscore as in other language it indicates "privateness" e.g. Python (though there it only indicates private at the class level).

```
        private void _FindPathToNode(Node currentNode, List<Node> visitedNodes, List<Node> path, int targetId, ref bool found)
```

But is there already a widely used convention?

Comment: Usually when I find I want to do this, I realise I need to make a new class with the "super" private method private. It can even be an inner class.

Comment: Good idea, and because a recursive method often only relies on it's parameters it could be static..

Comment: Sometimes when I want to make a super private method, I use an anonymous method inside the caller method.  That way, it really isn't callable by any other method.

Comment: Sounds more like refactoring would be good in such cases, e.g. splitting up a class into several classes that are allowed to call all  their methods.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can find, the naming convention proposed by Microsoft is `Core`.

Example:

```
public Add(Item item)
{
  AddCore(item);
}

public Replace(Item item1, Item item2)
{
  RemoveCore(item1);
  AddCore(item2);
}
```

See also this related question: [More private than private? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299216/more-private-than-private-c/1299380#1299380)