# How to forbid the use of fields instead of properties?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a property in my class that has a lot of logic in **set** accessor:

```
private String text;

public String Text
{
   get { return text; }
   private set
   {
      // some actions with a value
      value = value.Replace('a', 'b');

      text = value;
   }
}
```

How can I prevent other developers (or even me) from changing **field** instead of **property** inside of this class ?

If somebody writes something like this:

```
public Test(String text)
{
   this.text = text;
}
```

it will break the logic of my class !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Normally, classes should be small enough that this shouldn't be an issue. Since the field is `private`, only code inside the same type will have access to the field. However, if you need to highlight the importance, you could do:

```
[Obsolete("Use the Text property, or I break your legs; fair warning")]
private string text;

public string Text
{
#pragma warning disable 0618
    get { return text; }
    private set
    {
        // some actions with a value
        value = value.Replace('a', 'b');

        text = value;
    }
#pragma warning restore 0618
}
```

This doesn't *stop* them, but it may help prevent accidental usage of the field.

Comment: `or I break your legs (or mine)` (as he wanna prevent himself too)

Comment: Haha. It is great solution. It's not completely solve the problem, but I don't think there is a way to do it better then this, so I will mark this answer as correct. Thanks !

Comment: @edencore side note: you could probably use Roslyn to implement an exact "find all illegal field usage and warn about them" - the problem, though, is defining "illegal field usage" vs "legal field usage"

Comment: Another (equally ugly) approach would be to rename the field, for example `private string textNoSanitationWhenWrittenToDontUseWeWillBreakYourLegs;`.

Comment: @MarcGravell: indeed, there is one function `set` that is privileged since it is permitted to modify `text` and no other function is. One further function `get` is permitted to read but not write. That's the concept to be captured, but I don't know the state of the art in expressing that for static code analysis to enforce. Other than Binary Worrier's answer, of course, which expresses it neatly in language the compiler already understands.

Comment: @Marc: With the utmost respect (and you do indeed have my utmost respect mate), see my comment on this answer of an old duplicate of this question :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1299268/18797

Comment: @BinaryWorrier I followed that link hoping for an explanation rather than just "you should be shot"...

Comment: @Rawling That's why it's funny

Comment: @BinaryWorrier somebody who is touching the internals of the same class is already implicitly inside the usual protection barriers...

Comment: Grand, but I still think this is a bad way to prevent the field from being accessed directly. The warning is only useful if 1) the dev checks the warnings 2) decides to heed the warning. I wouldn't use a _hint_ to get you to do the right thing, when I can *force* you to do the right thing. If I thought every developer would look for and heed the warning, I'd probably trust them to look an inteli-sense comment. `/// Use Text property, not this field` would very nearly be as effective. I'd get the compiler to enforce this, not issue hints. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 9):

There is a correct way to do this. Consider the old adage "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection".

What you do is create a class that knows how to set the value of the text field properly.

```
class TextSetter
{
    private string text;
    public TextSetter(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get{ return text;}
        set{ text = value.Replace('a', 'b');}
    }
}
```

Then in your first class instead of 
`private string text;` you have `private TextSetter text`; now there is never any chance that someone will accidentally set the value directly.

you could even generalise this, if it's a common problem

```
class FieldSetter<T>
{
    private T field;
    private Func<T, T> setter;
    public FieldSetter(Func<T, T> setter, T field)
    {
        this.setter = setter
        Value = field;
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get{ return field;}
        set{ field = setter(value);}
    }
}
```

Feel free to rename as you see fit.

Comment: Not great in terms of allocations, though.

Comment: This is true, however it is _just another allocation_. If one more allocation on the class is going to break your heart you can make the class a struct and then you're back to a single allocation for Setter and the string reference `text`. 99% of the time, for 99% of the software folks write, the extra allocation matters less than keeping the intent of the code honest. We don't all suffer [Assult by GC](http://marcgravell.blogspot.ie/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html), few of us work with StackOverflow type volumes :p

Comment: . . . with the obvious caveat that you'd need to implement the struct properly (i.e. as an immutable type), which means you're back to an allocation for every assignment . . . maybe don't make the class a struct.

Comment: creating a new struct each time is not an allocation; the size would be the size of the contained data, presumably a single `string` reference - so no larger than the original

Comment: So something like `this.myDate = new DateTime(2014, 04, 14);` doesn't cause an allocation? This I did not know. It looks like it does, the `new` to create a new struct, which would then be copied over the old. I may look into this and see how it actually works, thanks.

Comment: In the case of `new SomeStruct(with args)`, the constructor simply writes over the top of the existing point in memory (which is why it is required that a struct constructor assigns to all fields). In the case of `new SomeStruct()` (no args), it simply zeros the memory. In neither case is there an allocation. The struct is inherently part of the containing scope: it is already allocated.

Comment: I added a separate answer to illustrate the `struct` usage more completely

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative approach, building on the [discussion with Binary Worrier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23055060/23354) (comments), you could do something like:

```
internal struct SanitizedText {
    private readonly string value;
    private SanitizedText(string value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public static implicit operator string (SanitizedText value) {
        return value.value;
    }
    public static implicit operator SanitizedText(string value) {
        if (value != null) value = value.Replace('a', 'b');
        return new SanitizedText(value);
    }
}
```

and then simply:

```
private SanitizedText text;
public string Text {
    get { return text; }
    set { text = value; }
}
```

This does all the same validation, but it is impossible to abuse: you cannot create a `SanitizedText` value that bypasses the validation; equally, it takes no more space (the size of the `struct` is the size of the contents: 1 reference), and requires no allocations. It even defaults to a `null` string in the same way.

Comment: +1 from me! (extra characters)

Comment: I would like this approach if there were some way to have a type include an "eager" promotion operator such that if compilation would fail with a type "as-is", the compiler should see what happens if it's eagerly promoted, so as to allow `someSanitizedString.Length`, or `someOtherTypeConvertibleFromString = someSanitizedString;` rather than `((string)someSanitizedString).Length` or `someOtherTypeConvertibleFromString = (string)someSanitizedString;.  Without such a feature, attempts to make a type behave like a built-in type end up creating very leaky abstractions.

Comment: @supercat (late comment): since the property `Text` (that you are only supposed to be using) returns `string`, then `Text.Length` is fine. If you use `someSanitizedString.Length`, you are using the backing field and that is what is being prevented.

Comment: @NetMage: My point was that it would be useful if one could use a field of a string-like type as though it was a string, without having to manually access the `Text` property.

Comment: @supercat Except the whole point of this is to disallow access to the field. If you want a string-like type that can be used as a string, that is a different issue entirely, and perhaps instead of a wrapper class, you should inherit from `String`. OTOH, if you want to complain that wrapper classes are too much work to create, that is an issue for C# development.

Comment: @NetMage: Beyond the question of whether something is a field or property, I think the idea I was getting at was the possibility of having a property that returns a low-cost wrapper object which could construct a potentially-expensive object on demand.  For example, one could have a `ConcatenatedString` object which holds a `String[]` where elements 1..N hold strings that were concatenated, and element 0, though initially null, will receive their concatenation the first time any code tries to use it as a string.  Attempting to concatenate multiple such strings, however,...

Comment: ...wouldn't need to create any actual `String[]` objects unless or until one tried to use the `ConcatenatedString` in a manner that would require a `String`.

Answer (score 5):

What you did already by setting the modifier to private for the field is as far as you can go. 
*Within* the class you should generally know what you do with its fields, where the logic happens.

Answer (score 1):

You could use collections (one per type) as "backing storage":

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> __intFields = new Dictionary<string, int>();
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> __stringFields = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static string StringProp
{
    get
    { 
        var fieldValue = default(string);
        __stringFields .TryGetValue("StringProp", out fieldValue);
        return fieldValue;
    }
    set
    {
        var manipulatedValue = applyOtherCode(value); // the rest of the code
        __stringFields ["StringProp"] = manipulatedValue
    }
}

public static int IntProp
{
    get
    { 
        var fieldValue = default(int);
        __intFields .TryGetValue("IntProp", out fieldValue);
        return fieldValue;
    }
    set
    {
        var manipulatedValue = applyOtherCode(value); // the rest of the code
        __intFields ["IntProp"] = manipulatedValue
    }
}
// There is no field for anyone to mistakenly access!
```

Ugly, verbose, un-refactorable,  ... but it gets the job done. If performance is the last of your concerns (if it even *is* one), you could grab the property name via Reflection and avoid magic strings.

*I originally had a single `<string, object>` collection ... but I hated it. One per type avoids casting data all the time*

Comment: Ugly, yes. In the getter, you should consider `TryGetValue` on the dictionary to not look for the key twice. In the setter you could just say `__backingFields["Prop"] = manipulatedValue;` with no `if` since that will replace or add as needed. The field could be made `readonly`. After these changes, it will still be very ugly, especially because of the cast from `object` to `string`.

Comment: Optimized. I also was hating that string to object cast and I changed the code to make it one-dictionary-per-type (this is starting to look like it would fit on codegolf ...). Cheers.